# Andriod Studio Used my CPU 100% and laptop goes to sleep

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

When i open Android studio CPU used 100% (only studio not emulator) continuously used 100%
and system goes to Sleep and i am facing this all time

I have following specification

- 8GB ram
- 128 gb SSD and 500 gb Hdd hard disk
- CPU  Intel(R)Core(TM)i7-5500U CPU @ 2.70 Ghz 2.90 GHZ

I already follow this tutorial but no result 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOSPoQnFiY8

[image]

Comment: It might be better if you ask this question on the SuperUser forum.

Comment: Sounds to me like your system might be going to shutting down due to overheating not 'going to sleep'. If the operation causes your system to fail midway it probably restarts each time and you keep getting in this scenario repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot looks like Android Studio is syncing your project, and high CPU usage is not unusual during sync. Does the syncing ever complete?

Also, can you close the project (File -> Close Project) then exit Android Studio, and try opening Android Studio again? See if you get high CPU usage. Just to confirm your Android Studio installation is good.

Your computer going to sleep might be due to your Windows settings/power plan, don't think it has anything to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in screenshot its syncing project but it goes to sleep almost whenever i open my android  studio & its not only in android studio when i open heavy game like pubgi  CPU 100% and again same issue..I have Latest window 10 and i reinstall it many times again and again but got same issue.
According to me When ever my cpu use 100% it goes to sleep.
I already set power plan option and set it no never sleep but again got same issue.
My machine is latest also software is latest but did not get why it goes to sleep